# String array not working with .equals

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception, equals

I am making a hangman game in Swing and am working on the section that checks if the value entered by the user  was in the word. I have put each letter of the word into an array. However when I enter a letter I know is in the array it outputs that it was not a letter. Using `.contains` creates an error message.

Code relating to the problem below.

```
private void checkcorrect() {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if(wordch[i].equals(inputString)) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            letter = true;
        }
    }

    if(letter==true) {
        System.out.println("Was a letter");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Not a letter");
    }
}

private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener{  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){ 
        String inputString = userInput.getText();
        userInput.setText("");
        System.out.println(inputString );
        checkcorrect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is just your development environment, This is a Java programming language question.

Comment: For your approach it looks correct, however I don't see how inputString gets from your `ActionListener` to your `checkcorrect()` method. You should also look at `String.contains()` for an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Also, we have no idea what wordch is. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Indent your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Comment: Add a your solution, we don't know what certain parts are.. Also post your output

Comment: `String inputString = userInput.getText();` does not set your inputString field.  It defines a *brand new variable* named inputString, which no code can see except for the code inside the actionPerformed method.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"Using `.contains` creates an error message."* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: BTW - `wordch[i]` together with the only method of `String` that breaks up the string into individual letters (`toCharArray()`) suggests the character array is a `char[]` rather than a `String[]`. **The `String` of a letter will not be the same as the `char` of the letter.**

Answer (score 0):

try ".contains"

```
    String word = "test";
    String[] letter = { "t"};
    boolean hasTheLetter = word.contains(letter[0]);
    System.out.println(hasTheLetter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it creates an error message when i try this I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.contains(String.java:2133)
 at HangMan.Test.checkcorrect(Test.java:101)

Comment: Post such exception output in the **question** as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check by using indexOf > 0.

```
String word = "abcdef";
String[] letter = {"d"};

boolean foundLetter = (word.indexOf(letter[0]) > 0);
if (foundLetter)
    // something
```

If you're getting a null pointer that means you're accessing a variable that doesn't exist/isn't declared yet.